# little mathematical thing : squares and roundings

Tags: scala, math, floating-point, integer-arithmetic

in scala, given the integers `d` & `x`, I would have a boolean expression which should be true if and only if `y = (x^2 - 1) / d^2` is a square.

I tried this:

```
(Math.sqrt((x * x - 1) / (d * d)).toInt * Math.sqrt((x * x - 1) / (d * d)).toInt == ((x * x - 1) / (d * d)))
```

but the 3-tuple `(x = 2, d = <all values tested>, y = 0.0)` seems to be always an answer of my problem, which is obviously wrong.
I think my error comes from the rounding made: if x=2, d=4 (for example) then `x * x - 1 == 3` and `d * d == 16` so the division leads to `0`.

do you know what is the good expression?

Comment: Not sure what you want. Give an example where you should return true and one for false.

Comment: hi; y=16 => true, y=64 => true, but y=63 => false

Comment: What is `x`, what is `d`, and how are you getting to `y=16=>true`, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

if n is  a round square, then Math.sqrt(n).toInt == Math.sqrt(n). In your case:

```
(Math.sqrt((x * x - 1) / (d * d)).toInt == Math.sqrt((x * x - 1) / (d * d)))
```

But before doing that, you need to make sure that x and d are **doubles**.
Try in REPL:

```
scala> val x = 1
scala> val d = 3
scala> x/d
```

A Int divided by an Int will result the rounded Int, so you are applying sqrt to zero.

Also due to float point arithmetic, you may want to compare like this instead:

```
(Math.sqrt((x * x - 1) / (d * d)).toInt - Math.sqrt((x * x - 1) / (d * d))) <= ZERO
```

where ZERO is replaced by a really small number like 0.00001

Answer (score 0):

Because this is integer division, you are checking whether `((x*x-1)/(d*d)).toInt` is a perfect square.  You can convert everything to doubles first, but if you want to stay in the realm of integers, check that the division should result in an integer:

```
( x*x-1 % d*d == 0 ) && Math.sqrt(y).toInt == Math.sqrt(y)
```